# Connecting React form with databse

Tags: reactjs

I created a form in react and i want to submit the details filled in react form inside database. I am not getting the way to connect React app with database, and to get and post values in database, Please help me with this.

Comment: What database are you using? Do you have a  server that communicates with database?

Comment: same question as @strdr4605 or do you want to store in localstorage?

Comment: You need backend application(server) which will handle that. Your react app needs to send it through HTTP POST to that server.

Comment: actually depends on which way you have to use it. for mysql  this is a good tutorial to start with. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN6Dx22cPRI